# Extract unique months from dates with year

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of date with daily sales value. I want to extract unique months from those dates so that I can prepare a report of monthly sales.

```
   Date      Sales
--------------------
07-09-2018   $3,000 
08-09-2018   $2,500 
09-10-2018   $2,800 
10-10-2018   $2,700 
11-11-2018   $2,500 
12-12-2018   $3,200 
13-12-2018   $2,900 
14-08-2018   $2,750 
15-08-2018   $2,875
```

[image]

Right now I am using a helper column and combination of formulas to extract unique months. I can also do this with `Pivot Table`. But I need some analysis on these data because in my actual data there many columns and needs some other few reports. So, if anybody can help me with do these without helper column and `Pivot Table`. `UDF` is second choice if it is not possible with built in functions.

Comment: You could probably just paste it over to a helper column and use excel’s built-in `remove duplicates` button. I know it’s not as neat but it’s probably a bit simpler than what you’re doing.

Comment: Those are manual process and apply right now but I am trying automate reports .

Comment: Then yeah you could use a dictionary and since you only have two values it fits neatly as a key value pair

Comment: Pivot table seems the way to go. Can you elaborate on why a pivot table won’t work? You can do analysis with GETPIVOTDATA or refer to the cells in pivot table manually just like you would any other table.... seems like your question is synonymous to “How can I build this pivot table without using a pivot table?”

Comment: Nonetheless, you could write a macro to do this. One way to do so would be to take @Marcucciboy2 first comment and convert that to a macro to generate your unique list. UDF is not ideal here unless you plan to provide an index to the unique value you want.

Comment: I already use macro. Also uses formulas with helper column and those works fine for me. But I was trying do without helper column.

Comment: Show us your current macro

Comment: For more control over your output, you could also use `Power Pivot` in Excel 2010+ aka `Get&Transform` in Excel 2016+

Answer (score 1):

For this example i have use Sheet1 and the results paste in Sheet2

Try:

```
Public Sub Get_Unique_Count_Paste_Array()

Dim Ob As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Item As Variant
Dim str As String
Dim r As Long
Dim Date_ As String
Dim Amount_ As Double

r = 1

Set Ob = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")


LR = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LR)
    Date_ = Format(rng.Value, "mmm-yy")
    Amount_ = Right(rng.Offset(0, 1).Value, Len(rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) - 1)

    If Len(Date_) > 0 Then
        str = Date_
        Ob(Date_) = Ob(Date_) + Amount_
    End If
Next rng

For Each Item In Ob.keys

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        .Cells(r, 1).Value = Item
        With .Cells(r, 2)
            .Value = Ob(Item)
            .NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US]#,##0.00"
        End With

    End With

    r = r + 1

Next Item

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, same approach I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

In the pivot table, click on the cell containing the date, select Group from the menu, then select the Months step.

Answer (score 0):

## Monthify

Before using the code, **study the customize section carefully**. A serious limitation is that each of the two column pairs contains **adjacent** columns, which is implemented in order to skip looping through the range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Monthify()

'**** Customize BEGIN ******************
  Const cStrDateCol As String = "B"     ' Column Letter of the Date
  Const cStrSalesCol As String = "C"    ' Column Letter of the Sales
  Const cStrMonthCol As String = "E"    ' Column Letter of the Resulting Month
  Const cStrTotalCol As String = "F"    ' Column Letter of the Resulting Sales
  Const cLngFirstRow As Long = 4        ' First Row of Initial Data
  Const cLngFirstRowResult As Long = 4  ' First Row of Resulting Data
  Const cLngLastRow As Long = 0         ' Last Row (If 0, it is calculated.)
  Const cStrSheet = "Sheet1"            ' Sheet Name. If "", then ActiveSheet.
  Const cStrMonth1 As String = "MMM"    ' Month Format Part 1
  Const cStrMonth2 As String = "-"      ' Month Format Part 2
  Const cStrMonth3 As String = "YY"     ' Month Format Part 3
'**** Customize END ********************

  Dim objWs As Worksheet

  Dim arrInit As Variant      ' Initial Array
  Dim arrResult As Variant    ' Resulting Array
  Dim lngLastRow As Long      ' Last Row Calculator
  Dim lngArr As Long          ' Array Row Counter
  Dim lngArr2 As Long         ' Array Additional Sort Row Counter
  Dim iArr As Integer         ' Array Columns Counter
  Dim vntArr As Variant       ' Array Temporary Variable
  Dim lngUnique As Long       ' (Unique) Months Count(er)
'*******************************************************************************
' Objects

  ' In Workbook
  With ThisWorkbook
    If cStrSheet <> "" Then
      Set objWs = .Worksheets(cStrSheet)
     Else
      Set objWs = .ActiveSheet
    End If
  End With

  ' In Worksheet
  With objWs
    ' Define last row of data.
    If cLngLastRow <> 0 Then ' Last row is defined.
      lngLastRow = cLngLastRow
     Else ' Last row isn't defined, has to be calculated.
      If .Cells(.Rows.Count, cStrDateCol) = "" Then ' Last cell is empty.
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cStrDateCol).End(xlUp).Row
       Else ' Last cell is not empty.
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cStrDateCol).Row
      End If
    End If
    ' Paste data into array.
    arrInit = Union(.Range( _
        Cells(cLngFirstRow, cStrDateCol), _
        Cells(lngLastRow, cStrDateCol)), .Range( _
        Cells(cLngFirstRow, cStrSalesCol), _
        Cells(lngLastRow, cStrSalesCol))).Value2
  End With

'*******************************************************************************
' Arrays

  ' Sort initial array by date ascending.
  For lngArr = LBound(arrInit) To UBound(arrInit)
    For lngArr2 = lngArr + 1 To UBound(arrInit)
      If arrInit(lngArr, 1) > arrInit(lngArr2, 1) Then
        For iArr = 1 To 2
          vntArr = arrInit(lngArr2, iArr)
          arrInit(lngArr2, iArr) = arrInit(lngArr, iArr)
          arrInit(lngArr, iArr) = vntArr
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' Convert date to months-year string.
  For lngArr = LBound(arrInit) To UBound(arrInit)
    arrInit(lngArr, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Format(arrInit(lngArr, 1), _
    cStrMonth1)) & cStrMonth2 & Format(arrInit(lngArr, 1), cStrMonth3)
  Next

  ' Count the number of unique month-year strings to determine the resulting
  ' array's size.
  vntArr = ""
  For lngArr = LBound(arrInit) To UBound(arrInit)
    If vntArr <> arrInit(lngArr, 1) Then
      vntArr = arrInit(lngArr, 1)
      lngUnique = lngUnique + 1
    End If
  Next

  ' Resize resulting array.
  ReDim arrResult(1 To lngUnique, 1 To 2)

  ' Write first column to resulting array.
  vntArr = ""
  lngUnique = 0
  For lngArr = LBound(arrInit) To UBound(arrInit)
    If vntArr <> arrInit(lngArr, 1) Then
      vntArr = arrInit(lngArr, 1)
      lngUnique = lngUnique + 1
      arrResult(lngUnique, 1) = arrInit(lngArr, 1)
    End If
  Next

  ' Write second column to resulting array.
  For lngArr2 = LBound(arrResult) To UBound(arrResult)
    vntArr = 0
    For lngArr = LBound(arrInit) To UBound(arrInit)
      If arrResult(lngArr2, 1) = arrInit(lngArr, 1) Then
        vntArr = vntArr + arrInit(lngArr, 2)
      End If
    Next
    arrResult(lngArr2, 2) = vntArr
  Next

'*******************************************************************************
'Objects

  ' Paste array into range.
  With objWs
    Union(.Range( _
        Cells(cLngFirstRowResult, cStrMonthCol), _
        Cells(cLngFirstRowResult + lngUnique - 1, cStrMonthCol)), .Range( _
        Cells(cLngFirstRowResult, cStrTotalCol), _
        Cells(cLngFirstRowResult + lngUnique - 1, cStrTotalCol))) = arrResult
  End With

  Set objWs = Nothing

End Sub
```